# Dual Android Map/Google Places Details Screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-places-api

I am having some real trouble with fragments!  I have a Results Activity class that runs two Fragments, lower half map with location and near google place markers, upper half will (or i want it too but it will not ruddy work) hold the address and details too a user selected marker.  I got everything, i can select the markers! i can load my location,i can get the nearest places and I can even run the place details on to another fragment (but it loads off screen).  But do you think i can load the details into the upper half of the screen!! (NO!) I need help, i pretty much been scratching my head over this for a while..its 20 to 2 and i cant face another day of it.. and  i know its something real small (it always is when I ask on Stack) but i just cant spot it.  Can you help me out please!
xml code that holds fragment, map_fragment, left search_frag for dynamic

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/results"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_banner"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout="@layout/result_hint">
    </RelativeLayout>
<fragment
    android:layout_below="@id/search_frag"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:name="boo.thefoodhunt.fragment.MapFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/template_map_view"/>
```

ResultsActivitiy.java:  I put a dummy fragment in there to see if it will load and it does, thought it might be easier to replace it with a new fragment (its not)

```
public class ResultsActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements MapFragment.MarkerClickCB {
    //Log
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    //Master data list Fragment

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        SelectFrag firstFragment = new SelectFrag();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.search_frag, firstFragment);
        ft.commit();
}
```

MapFragment.java
Part of the else if statement on public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker).  The uncommented code works and communicates the google place details a users selects, address and sends the details to a full screen fragment.

```
 if (marker.equals(this.myLocMarker) && nearby != null) {
            for (Marker placeMarker : nearby.keySet()) {
                placeMarker.setVisible(!placeMarker.isVisible());
            }
        } else if (nearby != null && nearby.containsKey(googLocation)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TempPlaceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PLACE", nearby.get(googLocation));
            startActivity(intent);
            //   mCallbacks.onMarkerSelected("PLACE", nearby);
            return true;
```

The code is a bit vaugue I am sorry I didnt want to post it all up due to there being about 5 different java.classes...just a point in the right direction will be fantastic.  The ResultsActivity.java holds the 2 fragments and has a results.xml. The MapFragment.java holds the map and google places details is in a frame.xml. The PlacesDetailsFragments holds the details and is held in a places.xml file.  Each fragment has activities, they are all over the place they seem to come as a pair..Im giving up tonight any help will be appreciated!

Comment: correction details do not load off screen, I meant to say on another screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out and thought id share.  Ok the fragments are written in the xml layout like so...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/results"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_banner"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout="@layout/result_hint"></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_frag"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout="@layout/template_map_view" />
```

search_frag and map_fragment needs to be RelativeLayout as going to be programmed within the activity you want them to appear

**ACTIVITY CLASS**
**search_frag**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        ....
        //sets up default fragment, will later be replaced with fragment when marker is selected
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) == null) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SelectFrag firstFragment = new SelectFrag();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.search_frag, firstFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
...
```

**map_frag**

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }
       mMap = new MapFragment();
        mMap.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.map_fragment, mMap).commit();
    }
```

**MAP FRAGMENT**

```
  MarkerClickCB mCallbacks; //communicates with the activity
   //interface set up
     public interface MarkerClickCB {
            void onMarkerSelected(String place, GoogePlaces place1);
        }

    ....

 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            if (!mClusterManager.onMarkerClick(marker)) {
                googLocation = marker;
                cluster.getPosition();
                if (googLocation.equals(userLocMarker) && clusts2 == null) {
                    searchFilter();
                }
                if (marker.equals(userLocMarker) && nearby != null) {
                    for (Marker placeMarker : nearby.keySet()) {
                        placeMarker.setVisible(!placeMarker.isVisible());
                    }
                } else if (cluster != null) {

                    mCallbacks.onMarkerSelected("PLACE", clickedClusterItem.getPlace());
                    getDistance(clickedClusterItem.getPosition().latitude, clickedClusterItem.getPosition().longitude);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

..Now back to the activity class that holds the previously programmed fragments.  We need to replaces the search_frag with the new fragment that holds the google place information for the selected marker.

The activity class needs to implement the callback data for the communication of data from the map fragment

**BACK TO THE ACTIVITY CLASS**

```
public  class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MapFragment.MarkerClickCB
....
   //previous fragment info//  
...
     public void onMarkerSelected(String near, GoogePlaces googPlace) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            PlaceFragment fragment = PlaceFragment.newInstance(googPlace);
            ft.replace(R.id.search_frag, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

..Replacement fragment that holds the data
**PLACE FRAGMENT**

```
    final static String PLACES_ID = "GoogePlaces";

    //Creates fragment object with details

    public static PlaceFragment newInstance(GoogePlaces place) {
            PlaceFragment fragment = new PlaceFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(PLACES_ID, place);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragment;
        }

//this bit got a bit messy for me - welcome to comment with improvements 

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        place = (GoogePlaces) getArguments().getSerializable(PLACES_ID);



 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_place_detail, container, false);

    this.context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    Log.i("PLACE EXAMPLE", "Place Detail Activity");


        place = (GoogePlaces) getArguments().getSerializable(PLACES_ID);
...

        getActivity().setTitle(place.getName());
        String placesKey = getResources().getString(R.string.places_key);

//connect to google places - to gather eatery details
        String placesRequest = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?" +
                "key=" + placesKey + "&reference=" + place.getReference();
        PlacesDetailReadFeed detailTask = new PlacesDetailReadFeed();
        detailTask.execute(new String[]{placesRequest});

       ......

    return view;
    }
```

OK, as a novice(ish) programmer this was pretty hard going for me I have to admit, any pointers, critique for code clean up will be appreciated